# LNK1104 cannot open file libboost_random-vc140-mt-1_61.lib and others

Tags: c++, boost

I can't find any text reference to *libboost_random-vc140-mt-1_61.lib* in any project file or source file, yet Visual Studio 2015 really seems to need it. If I rename another static library *libboost_random-vc140-mt-1_61.lib*, the linker completes(not pulling any symbols from the bogus boost library). I had used b2.exe at some point in the past to generate such a file, but recently have mounted a Visual Studio project for boost system and random, where the static library outputs have different names. Where are these old references coming from?

Comment: Maybe the [autolinking](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/boost/config/auto_link.hpp)?

Comment: Either that, or your problem goes away with a "rebuild all".

Comment: I have completely rebuilt the project, starting with zero binary files.. magically, after building, libboost_random-vc140-mt-1_61.lib shows up in the .obj files when i grep.

Comment: hmm.. autolink eh?

Comment: @DanMašek Thank you! I defined BOOST_ALL_NO_LIB to disable auto_link. Works perfectly. How do I mark this as an answer?

Comment: @sfl-andreas There, wrote it up as a proper answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're on Windows, this is likely to be the result of the [auto-linking](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/more/getting_started/windows.html#auto-linking) functionality of Boost.

More details are in [boost/config/auto_link.hpp](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/boost/config/auto_link.hpp).

You can disable this by defining `BOOST_ALL_NO_LIB`.